# Infinite sum of reciprocal shifted Fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fibonacci-numbers

I found on Wikipedia the following infinite sum :

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+F_{2k+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

There is no reference for this sum in the article and I couldn't find it anywhere else .I have no idea how to prove it so I'm asking for help .

Thank you for your time to help me !

Comment: I confirm ... Yes, the identity is out there!

Comment: There are topic about Series and Fibonnaci sequences
[question] http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281113/fibonacci-sequence-and-series-limits?rq=1

Comment: @nickchalkida  Please tell me where I can find the proof . Thanks .

Comment: I found  the paper "Transcendence of Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction and reciprocal sums of Fibonacci numbers" by "Daniel Duverney, Keiji Nishioka, Kumiko Nishioka, and Iekata Shiokawa". It is an open pdf. There exists a proof, like a Corollary.

Comment: Better to give the link [Transcendence of Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction and reciprocal sums of Fibonacci numbers][1]


  [1]: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.pja/1195509914

Comment: @ nickchalkida  I found the paper but I can't find this identity there .

Comment: I thought the third sum in Corollary in page 3 (142) of the paper was the sum under question. It differs however slightly ... I apologize.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use [Binet's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html) formula for $F_{2k+1}$:-
$$F_{2k+1}=\frac{\phi^{2k+1}-(-\phi)^{-(2k+1)}}{\sqrt{5}}$$
where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

The summation (after substitution of $F_{2k+1}$ and partial fraction decomposition) becomes a telescoping sum
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+F_{2k+1}}&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{5}\phi^{2k+1}}{\sqrt{5}\phi^{2k+1}+\phi^{4k+2}+1}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}(1+\sqrt{5})}{2\phi^{2k+1}+\sqrt{5}+1}-\frac{\sqrt{5}(\sqrt{5}-1)}{2\phi^{2k+1}+\sqrt{5}-1}\right)\\&=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}-x_1+x_1-x_2+x_2+\cdots+\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} x_k\\&=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\end{align}$$ 
where $$x_1=\frac{\sqrt{5}(\sqrt{5}-1)}{2\phi^{1}+\sqrt{5}-1}=\frac{\sqrt{5}(1+\sqrt{5})}{2\phi^{3}+\sqrt{5}+1},x_2=\frac{\sqrt{5}(\sqrt{5}-1)}{2\phi^{3}+\sqrt{5}-1}=\frac{\sqrt{5}(1+\sqrt{5})}{2\phi^{5}+\sqrt{5}+1},\cdots$$
and $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} x_k=0$.