# Proof of sum of ratio of Fibonacci numbers is less than 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, fibonacci-numbers

Using notation $F_1 = 1, F_2 = 1, F_3 = 2, F_4 = 3, F_5 = 5, ...$ for Fibonacci numbers prove that for any positive integer $n$:
$$\frac{1}{1\cdot 2} + \frac{2}{1\cdot 3} + \frac{3}{2 \cdot 5} + · · · + \frac{F_n}{F_{n-1}\cdot F_{n+1}} < 2$$

I attempted to use induction on this problem, but could not finish the proof. Are there any alternative methods or tips to help prove this? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure this helps, but $F_n^2 = F_{n-1}F_{n+1}\pm 1$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281113/fibonacci-sequence-and-series-limits. Basically you only need $F_n = F_{n+1} - F_{n-1}$ and the sum telescopes.

Comment: We should mark this as duplicated.